# "The object id ... is invalid"

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I have script in which I run commands like  Add-PnPFile, Add-PnPClientSidePage, etc.

In compeletly random situation from my point of view, such error occurs,
Is there any solution to this problem?

`Add-PnPFile : The object id "site:2c03fa85-c130-42db-b9e0-97db69f58744:web:7874845e-bd88-44ab-9f93-2d3cf305b5ca:folder:3a298b2b-17b2-4f99-9949-2edb79930fe8"
is invalid`.

```
Write-Log -Level INFO -Message "Upload 'file1.pptx'"
Add-PnPFile -Path ".\content\file1.pptx" -Folder "Shared Documents"
Write-Log -Level INFO -Message "Upload 'file2.pptx'"
Add-PnPFile -Path ".\content\file2.pptx" -Folder "Shared Documents"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this after deleting and recreating sites at the same url? Looks like a known issue and I've experienced this as well: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/2019

Wait a few minutes after deleting the site to recreate and run the scripts.